# Writing User Defined Function to Copy& paste, then sort and finally Sum after a specific column

Tags: sorting, excel, user-defined-functions, vba

I am trying to write a custom function which can be called as Cell formula. It basically takes  Source range, target range, sorting range and from where data should be summed as input arguments. The function copies from source range and pastes in target range. Then sorts with the help of sort range. After, it should sum the data after specified number columns removing the remaining data

```
      Function Sort_Column(MaCol As String, SortCol As String, TarCol As String, x As Long)
        Dim OneRange As Range
        Dim Ws As Worksheet`enter code here`
          Set Ws = Workbooks("test4.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
             Ws.Range(MaCol & "," & SortCol).Copy
             Ws.Range(TarCol).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


          Set OneRange = Ws.Range(TarCol)
              TarColNa = Right(TarCol, 1)
              TarColRa = Right(TarCol, 1) & "2"
                 Set acell = Ws.Range(TarColRa)
              OneRange.Sort Key1:=acell, Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

              TarCell = Range(TarColNa & 1).Column
              LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, TarCell).End(xlUp).Row

            Y = x + 1
           SumCol = "=SUM(" & TarColNa & Y & ":" & TarColNa & LastRow & ")"
           Range(TarColNa & Y) = SumCol
           Range(Left(TarCol, 1) & Y) = " All Other"
           Range(Left(TarCol, 1) & Y + 1 & ":" & Left(TarCol, 1) & LastRow).ClearContents
           Range(TarColNa & Y + 1 & ":" & TarColNa & LastRow).ClearContents

           Range(Left(TarCol, 1) & "2").Select

     End Function
```

Unfortunately, the above user-defined function when tried as a cell formula is returning #VALUE

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `The function copies from source range and pastes in target range.` A UDF cannot do that... i.e make changes to any other cell.

Comment: you may want to see [THIS LINK](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/creating-custom-functions-HA001111701.aspx) quote from that link `they perform calculations instead of taking actions. Certain kinds of statements (such as statements that select and format ranges) are excluded from custom functions. In this article, you learn how to create and use custom functions.`

Comment: @SiddharthRout I went through the link. I have to use a user-defined function. I wonder if there is any other way to achieve the result using user-defined function. Thank you for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

As Siddarth says, a UDF can only return data to the cells it is entered into. So the only way to make your UDF work is to change it to return an array and enter it as a multi-cell array formula into the target range.
 See http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/writing-efiicient-vba-udfs-part5-udf-array-formulas-go-faster/ for an example of creating a multi-cell array UDF.
 You enter a multi-cell array formula by selecting the target range of cells, entering the formula in the formula bar and pressing Ctrl/Shift/Enter.